# Solve inequality $x^4+x^3+x+1>0$.

Tags: inequality

Can someone solve this inequality with solutions:
$$x^4+x^3+x+1>0.$$
There are 2 answers that I got:

1. No Solution, since it will have imaginary numbers as a factor
2. When you equal the remaining inequality to 0 after factoring it once. Getting a factor of: $$(x+1)(x+1)(x+1)(x+1)>0$$ 
   Which is not exact.

Comment: Hint:  $x=-1$  is a root.  Use that to factor your quartic.

Comment: The correct factorization is $$x^4+x^3+x+1 = (x+1)(x^3+1)= (x+1)^2(x^2-x+1)$$ so it is always $\ge 0$ and it vanishes only at $x=-1$.

Comment: Please provide more descriptive titles in the future.

Comment: So the answer will be: $$All Real Numbers except {-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x^4+x^3+x+1=(x+1)^2(x^2-x+1)>0\iff x^2-x+1>0\text{ and }x\neq -1$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that 
$$x^4+x^3+x+1=(x^3+1)(x+1)=(x^2-x+1)(x+1)^2=\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\right)(x+1)^2.$$
Hence $x^4+x^3+x+1$ is always positive with the exception of $x=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$x^4+x^3=x^3(x+1)$$
So 
$$x^4+x^3+x+1=x^3(x+1)+(x+1)=(x^3+1)(x+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

note that $$x^4+x^3+x+1=(x+1)^2(x^2-x+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

I think the factor you get should be
$$ x^{4} + x^{3} + x + 1 = x^{3} \left( x + 1 \right) + \left( x + 1 \right) = \left( x + 1 \right) \left( x^{3} + 1 \right) = \left( x + 1 \right) ^{2} \left( x^{2} - x + 1 \right) = \left( x + 1 \right) ^{2} \left( x^{2} - 2x \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{3}{4} \right) = \left( x + 1 \right) ^{2} \left( \left( x - \dfrac{1}{2} \right) ^{2} + \dfrac{3}{4} \right) \geq 0 . $$
So unless x=-1, the inequality always holds.